# Javascript code challenge not passing

Tags: javascript, function, console

Given a string or number write a function tea42 that takes as input a string or number and returns a string where every '2' charcter or digit has been replaced     with a t. 
    Test cases are :

```
Test.assertEquals(tea42(2), 't', 'Twos you lose!') 
Test.assertEquals(tea42('2'), 't', 'Twos you lose!')
Test.assertEquals(tea42(102), '10t', 'Twos you lose!')
Test.assertEquals(tea42('m2'),'mt', 'Twos you lose!')
Test.assertEquals(tea42('pre2ty'),'pretty', 'Twos you lose!')
```

Here's my code :

```
function tea42(input) {
  for (i =0; i <= input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] === "2") {
      return (input.replace( "2", "t"));
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: My guess is that you need to cast `input` to a string.  Such as `input = input + '';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop, just check if there is a 2 in the input (use `input+""` to convert it to string in order to be able to check it with `indexOf`

```
function tea42(input) {
    var output = input + "";
    if (output.indexOf("2") !== -1) output = output.replace(/2/g, "t");
    return output;
}
```